# Sublime Text - Exclude from Go To, but not from explicit "Find in Folder" searches of that dir

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

So I have a `deps` folder, which I don't want to be included in Go To(CMD+P). `binary_file_patterns` does exactly this, plus excluding the folder from general searches, but it has what I think is a fatal flaw. If I DO want to find something in the dep, and I explicitly right-click it and hit "Find in Folder", it won't search the folder. I want it excluded from non-explicit searches of that folder, but if I explicitly search within the `deps` folder, then it should search the `deps` folder, no? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not really. If it's excluded from search, it's excluded from search. You'd have to search it explicitly from outside of Sublime.

Comment: @MattDMo That seems like bad UX to me. I want it excluded from search most of the time, but when I explicitly search it, I want to search it.